# C#: random number issue

Tags: c#, random

See the following:

```
   for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        // do some stuff
        r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        iRandom = r.Next(30000);
        // do some other stuff
   }
```

Don't ask me how, but iRandom is sometimes the same for both iterations of the loop.  I need iRandom to be different for each iteration.  How do I do this?

Comment: What might be happening is each step executes so fast that the next `Random` instance gets seeded with the same value. Have you tried calling the `Random()` constructor with no arguments (it may give you a better time value for your seed)?

Comment: I'm assuming that is what's happening. It is surprising however because I thought Ticks was measured in nanoseconds.

Comment: dunno, I know nothing about .NET so I could be wrong

Comment: Beeing measured in nanoseconds (btw it is hundreds of nanoseconds - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) does not mean it changes every hundred nanoseconds. DateTime precision is 10ms ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) which is pretty much forever for any simple program. As result all your calls to .Ticks return the same value.

Answer (score 8):

Change your loop to this:

```
    r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

   for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    // do some stuff
    iRandom = r.Next(30000);
    // do some other stuff
   }
```

In other words, put the creation of the Random object outside the loop.

Comment: If the seed is Ticks, why would this be necessary?

Comment: +1, it shouldn't be necessary to generate a new instance of `Random` each time a random value is desired.

Comment: If the proper way to generate the next random number is using .Next(), I wouldn't trust anything else to be completely reliable.

Comment: @Craig: The RNG is indeed seeded using the system clock if you use its parameterless constructor (or, I suppose, using the `Ticks` value the way you've coded it here), but you're creating the new objects in extremely rapid succession, which is causing them to be seeded with the same value. Your `for` loop runs much faster than you think!

Comment: The suggestion is to make the code efficient but not an answer for why iRandom is same for both iterations.

Comment: @Cybernate: It has nothing to do with efficiency. Creating a new instance of the `Random` class is going to extremely cheap. The problem is that you're creating those instances back-to-back, causing them to be seeded with the same value. Computers can execute lots of instructions very quickly now.

Comment: Right.  Plus, its just the "right" way to create the next random number using Random.Next() instead of creating an entirely new instance of the object.

Answer (score 3):

try creating your Random with a non time-based seed, otherwise the seed may be the same (and the random number same also)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    // do some stuff
    r = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    iRandom = r.Next(30000);
    // do some other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some surprises with Math.Random doubles versus RNGCryptoServiceProvider, try plotting the results of the following (say, using a spreadsheet). This code will run in LinqPad (www.LinqPad.net). It's worth a look :)

```
void Main()
{
{
    var ds = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(i => new Random(i).NextDouble());
    ds.Dump();
}
{
    var csp = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var bs = new byte[8 * 30];
    var ds = new double[30];
    csp.GetBytes(bs);

    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        var d = BitConverter.ToDouble(bs, i * 8);
        while (d == 0D || Double.IsNaN(d))
        {
            var bytes = new byte[8];
            csp.GetBytes(bytes);
            d = BitConverter.ToDouble(bs, 0);
        }
        ds[i] = Math.Log10(Math.Abs(d));
    }

    ds.Dump();
}
```

}

Comment: I can't handle the anticipation: what's the surprise?

Comment: @Cody: The Math.Random one shows a very interesting non-random structure :)  Of course, it's not advertised as a cryptographically sound PRNG, so there's no grounds for outrage. Still, it's mildly surprising that there is so much regularity so near the surface.

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "non-random"? There are a lot of definitions to the word "random" floating around, some of them mathematically rigorous and others more colloquial. Of course it's not designed for cryptography (there are other functions for that), but there is definitely a chance for regularity to true randomness.

Comment: @Cody: Informally, if I plot a sequence of numbers and see a "visually obvious" or "crystalline" structure (double quotes denoting informal usage of the words), such as a sawtooth or a sine wave or something that I could easily model off-the-cuff with little combinations of polynomials or 1st-year calculus functions, I would call that "non-random." Again, informally; I know that precise definitions of randomness are difficult. Perhaps "predictable" is a good stand-in for "non-random?"

Answer (score 1):

A REALLY nice explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try seeding with a new Guid, or, better yet, use the Cryto provider... Here's a Stko article with code

[Best way to seed Random() in singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399039/best-way-to-seed-random-in-singleton)

Comment: @Craig: Using the [`Guid.NewGuid` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx), for starters. But this is **way** overkill for *seeding* a random number generator.

Comment: @Cody: GUID generates characters as well - how could you use it as a seed?

Comment: @Craig: I have no idea. I'm not the one who suggested it. When used properly, the `Random` class does everything I've ever wanted it to do.

Comment: Here's a way to seed with a Guid Random rnd = new Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 0));

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now.Ticks is a Int64 type. If you cast to an int, it could be casting to the same value for the seed and therefore giving you the same random number.

No need to reseed or recreate the Random object once it is created. Just reuse the object and obtain the next random number.