# c# random numbers in abstract properties

Tags: c#, random, abstract

How do I create an abstract property that can be a random number?

Parent.cs:

```
public abstract float ageInYears{get;}
```

Child.cs:

```
public override float ageInYears{
     get{
          return Random.Range(0, 10);
     }
}
```

How do I ensure that Child.cs sets ageInYears to a random number, and that random number stays the same whenever accessed in the future?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about what you're looking for? Do you just want the property to be initialized to be random?

Comment: "stagnation of the random number" What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "stagnation". Do you mean you want a `Child` object to always return the same value for `ageInYears`?

Comment: Sounds like you want a property that gets a random initial value and stays the same afterwards. Simply use a `private readonly` backing-field that you initialize in the constructor

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for, HimBromBeere. Can You provide an answer using that implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private float? age;
public override float ageInYears{
 get{
      if(!age.HasValue) {
          age = 10.0f * ((float) x.Next()) / ((float) int.MaxValue);
      }
      return age;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a method I call a Managed Entropy Source. Just a static class that creates a Random, then I call methods on MES, which being static, makes all random numbers come from the same 'stream', preventing the problem where 1000+ rng pulls can sometimes have just 2 values.

Also you can make nice wrappers, like CoinFlip() or Pick(list)

Helps when debugging random events, since you can swap out your MES implementation for a fake one that just reads from a file, or maybe inputbox's the number from the user ;)

Comment: I like the idea of a static class handling the randomness. Can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

An cryptographically seeded instance of `Random` is created per thread (inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12952155/315689).

The backing property `_ageInYears` is initialized during the creation of each `Child`. Subsequent calls to the public `ageInYears` property will return the same value for a given instance of `Child`.

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Random _random;

    private float _ageInYears;
    public override float ageInYears { get { return _ageInYears; } }

    public Child()
    {
        if (_random == null)
        {
            var cryptoResult = new byte[4];
            new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(cryptoResult);

            int seed = BitConverter.ToInt32(cryptoResult, 0);

            _random = new Random(seed);
        }
        _ageInYears = (float)_random.NextDouble() * 10f;
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pmM5EC

Comment: Cool answer. Is there a way to accomplish enforced variables in child classes that support random numbers without having to do the whole abstract {get;} and threading thing? I feel like it's more work than it should be. For example, if I **didn't** need it to be enforced, I could simply do `float ageInYears` in parent.cs and `ageInYears = new Random()` in the Main method of child.cs.

Comment: Can you specify what the difference is between "enforced" and "not enforced"? You edited the question to `ageInYears` of each `Child` should not change. I have updated code to reflect this.

Comment: This answer creates integral values from 0 through 9 represented as floats. I presume since OP is using a float he wants to allow an age with non-discrete value

Comment: @Steve - I've updated my answer to include floating point values in the range [0,10)